# CSS & HTML Spacing Issue

Tags: html, css, position, edit

Hi guys I am trying to add to my page a menu bar down the left hand side

my issue is its pushing all the html below this out of line.  The menu bar is showing but its not able to be clicked on.

How can I sort this issue please..

Many thanks in advance

here is some code I added to the HTML and the Stylesheet.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta https-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Site tile </title>
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a class="active" href="https://Sitehere.com"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
  <a href="https://Sitehere.com "><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
  <a href=mailto:email@here.com><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
  <a href="https://sitehere.com/signup"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a> 
</div>
<!--CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-light.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--/CSS-->

<!--JS-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script>
```

This is what I added to the style sheet..

```
}

.icon-bar {
    width: 90px; /* Set a specific width */
    background-color: #555; /* Dark-grey background */
}

.icon-bar a {
    display: block; /* Make the links appear below each other instead of side-by-side */
    text-align: center; /* Center-align text */
    padding: 16px; /* Add some padding */
    transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Add transition for hover effects */
    color: white; /* White text color */
    font-size: 36px; /* Increased font-size */
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #000; /* Add a hover color */
}

.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Add an active/current color */
}
```

How do i stop this pushing all the HTML text below down the page? and is there any reason the bar can be seen but not interacted with?

many thanks in advance!

FULL HTML

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta https-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Coming Soon </title>
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a class="active" href="https://EXAMPLE.COM"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
  <a href="https://EXAMPLE.COM/support "><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
  <a href=mailto:admin@SITE.COM><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
  <a href="https://EXAMPLE.COM/signup"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a> 
</div>
<!--CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-light.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--/CSS-->

<!--JS-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: new Date(2017, 8-1, 25)}); 
    //Replace above date with your own, to find out more visit https://keith-wood.name/countdown.html
});
</script>
<!--/JS-->

</head>
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ 
var tlJsHost = ((window.location.protocol == "httpss:") ? "httpss://secure.comodo.com/" : "https://www.trustlogo.com/");
document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + tlJsHost + "trustlogo/javascript/trustlogo.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
//]]>
</script>
<body>
<!--DARK OVERLAY-->
<div class="overlay"></div>
<!--/DARK OVERLAY-->
<!--WRAP-->
<div id="wrap">
    <!--CONTAINER-->
    <div class="container">
        <img src="images/LOGO.png" alt="LOGO" class="image-align" />
        <h1>
            <span>We are</span><br/>
            Reaching For <span class="yellow">The Moon.</span>
        </h1>
        <p>SITE TEXT HERE.</p>
        <div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="Subscribe to find out when we are done">
            <input type="submit" value="GO!">
        </div>
        </form>
        <p class="copyright">Designed by <a href="https://EXAMPLE.COM" target="_blank">Investex.pro</a></p>
        <img src="images/comodo_secure_seal_76x26_transp.png" alt="Comodo" class="image-align" />
    </div>
    <!--/CONTAINER-->

<!--/WRAP-->

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
TrustLogo("https://EXAMPLE.COM/images/comodo_secure_seal_76x26_transp.png", "CL1", "none");
</script>
<a  href="httpss://ssl.comodo.com" id="comodoTL">Comodo SSL</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to include the rest of your html/css for context. You might try adding `.icon-bar { float: left; }`

Comment: I have included the HTML  from the index page above.

Comment: This is why you should give all your code over at the very first time. You **full html** shows your wrapper is above/before the body tag and not closed. Move it inside the body tag and try the float option @MichaelCoker suggested.

Comment: Thanks Ill mind that for future posts.   I have added the float option and changed the background colour on refresh my whole background changed and I lost my background..  Frustration is high right now haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To stop the bar pushing the following content down, you can just set it to [`float: left;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float?v=control) to take it out of the normal text flow and put it to the left. Now the text will appear next to the bar.

Also if you can't click on the bar, there is maybe a hidden div with a higher z-index. I would recommend checking your web inspector to find out, why you can't click on the bar.

Also: **Make sure, your markup is valid**! Your head section is a bit messy. `<div>` elements e.g. don't belong here.

```css
.icon-bar {
  width: 90px;
  background-color: #555;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  color: white;
  font-size: 36px;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #000;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

```html
<!-- Add icon library -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="icon-bar">
    <a class="active" href="https://Sitehere.com"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
    <a href="https://Sitehere.com "><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
    <a href=mailto:email@here.com><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a>
    <a href="https://sitehere.com/signup"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
    sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
    Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should replace your html down the link tags and close the head tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta https-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<title>Site tile </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!--CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-light.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--/CSS-->
</head>


<div id="wrapper">
<div class="icon-bar">
  <a class="active" href="https://Sitehere.com"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a> 
  <a href="https://Sitehere.com "><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a> 
  <a href=mailto:email@here.com><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a> 
  <a href="https://sitehere.com/signup"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></a> 
</div>
</div>


<!--JS-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script>
```

Comment: I have attempted the code but the menu bar is still only accessible when you hit refresh for a split second then it vanishes

Comment: change the background color for the a element

Comment: .icon-bar a { background:#555;
    display: block; /* Make the links appear below each other instead of side-by-side */
    text-align: center; /* Center-align text */
    padding: 16px; /* Add some padding */
    transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Add transition for hover effects */
    color: white; /* White text color */
    font-size: 36px; /* Increased font-size */
}

Answer (score 0):

you should change the background color for the a element

}

```
.icon-bar a {
    display: block; /* Make the links appear below each other instead of side-by-side */
    background:#555;
    text-align: center; /* Center-align text */
    padding: 16px; /* Add some padding */
    transition: all 0.3s ease; /* Add transition for hover effects */
    color: white; /* White text color */
    font-size: 36px; /* Increased font-size */
}
```

Comment: Thanks I am relatively new to this and its really becoming a pain..  I have added the code from above I also checked in console but there are no errors showing for any elements.

Comment: How do I add it as element?

Comment: The "a" tag element is already exists,  just change the css style of it

Comment: background:#555;  When I edit this value the whole page changes though it removes the background that I have set and make the page look rather strange.   the icon's are in the correct place now and spacing is correct they are just unable to be clicked on.  I checked console but there are no errors showing for the site or warnings regarding it.